# Ruby on Rails: How do I pass a variable along with f.submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails: How do I pass a variable along with f.submit?

Comment: In an hidden field in your form?

Comment: Actually I don't think it's clear at all what you're asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no you can't pass along with submit button.

but you get name of button as `params[:commit]` in controller

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you'rer passing would be the data in the form, yes?

What parameter/data are you trying to receive? If you want to know the name of the user who performed the submit, or the current time, or something similar, there are other ways to do it.

As Salil mentioned, the parameters/form data are accessible in the controller via the "params" array.